# How to set response to adapter in android

Tags: android

Hello in the below code I am getting the response from the server in the form json.

Now I am setting arraylist to the adapter named as SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter class.

Below code describes the list fetching from server and then adding to the arraylist and then set to the adapter.

Managelist.java:

```
 private void doTheAutoRefresh() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Write code for your refresh logic

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (getActivity ());
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Communicating...");
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(API.URL_BASE)
                        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client (client)
                        .build();
                API service = retrofit.create (API.class);
                Call<Operator> userCall = service.getopetaorlist ();
                userCall.enqueue(new Callback<Operator> () {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call <Operator> call, Response <Operator> response) {


                        if (response != null && response.code ( ) == 200&& response.isSuccessful ()) {

                            String Lists = new Gson ( ).toJson (response.body ( ));
                            Log.d ("Status", Lists);
                            //progressDialog.dismiss ( );
                            //Log.d ("Response body", new Gson ( ).toJson (response.body ( )));
                           // String Lists = new Gson ( ).toJson (response.body ( ));
                            //JSONArray jsonArray = null;


                            try {
                                arrayList = new ArrayList <> ( );
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (Lists);
                                JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray ("list");
                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject ( );
                                jsonObject1 = result.getJSONObject (0);
                                System.out.println (jsonObject1);
                                String email = String.valueOf (jsonObject1.get ("email"));
                                System.out.println (email);
                                arrayList.add (email);
                                String username = String.valueOf (jsonObject1.get ("username"));
                                System.out.println (username);
                                arrayList.add (username);
                                String mobileNumber = String.valueOf (jsonObject1.get ("mobileNumber"));
                                System.out.println (mobileNumber);
                                arrayList.add (mobileNumber);
                                progressDialog.dismiss ( );
                                //String id=result.getString (0);
                                //Integer status=result.getInt (1);



                                // Creating Adapter object
                                SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter = new SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter((Context) getActivity (), arrayList);


                                // Setting Mode to Single to reveal bottom View for one item in List
                                // Setting Mode to Mutliple to reveal bottom Views for multile items in List
                                //((SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setMode(Attributes.Mode.Single);

                                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);



                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace ( );

                            }

                        }

                        else  {
                            progressDialog.dismiss ();
                            Log.d("Response errorBody", String.valueOf(response.errorBody()));
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Operator> call, Throwable t) {
                        // lv.setAdapter (adapter);
                        System.out.println("onFailure");
                        System.out.println(t.fillInStackTrace());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity (), "Some error occurred -> ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                        // progressDialog.dismiss();



                    }

                });
            }


        }, 5000);
        return ;
    }
```

In the below adapter I am acessing the arraylist and then set to the invidual textview.But this is not working .

It is setting all the values to single class

SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.java:

```
public class SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerSwipeAdapter<SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.SimpleViewHolder> {


    private Context mContext;
    private List <Operator> operatorlist;
    ArrayList arrayList;
    Dialog myDialog;
    String building_name;


    public SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List <Operator> List) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.operatorlist = List;
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycleview_operator_item, parent, false);
        myDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
    }
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
List<Operator> op= Collections.singletonList (operatorlist.get (position));
    String username=op.get (0).getList ().get (0).getUsername ();
    viewHolder.tvName.setText (username);
```

POJO.java:

```
public class Operator {

    @SerializedName("list")
    private List <GetOperatorList> list;

    public List <GetOperatorList> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List <GetOperatorList> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the code where you are requesting data and loading into operatorlist.

Comment: Attach meaningful code here, what is `operatorlist` here? Have you used any POJO in the `SimpleViewHolder`?

Answer (score 0):

```
simple...assuming u getting array of emails hope yoou created a pojo  if not,

public class GetCities {
    private String email;
    private String id;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private String username;

    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public void setEmail(String value) { this.email = value; }

    public String getID() { return id; }
    public void setID(String value) { this.id = value; }

    public String getMobileNumber() { return mobileNumber; }
    public void setMobileNumber(String value) { this.mobileNumber = value; }

    public String getUsername() { return username; }
    public void setUsername(String value) { this.username = value; }
}
```

in adapter just pass ArrayList

in on bindviewholder get as ,

GetCities cities=operatorlist[position]